# Подключение домена к сайту

Tags: домен

Купив домен:

> knowledge-book.ru.com

Возник вопрос как связать домен с сайтом ?

Comment: в ЛК на рег.ру надо указать IP адрес сервера, где расположен сайт. Если хостинг тоже покупной, то там в админке также следует прописать имя домена.  Если сайт на своем сервере, то настраивайте вэб-сервер соответственно.

Comment: Простите если кажусь слишком тупая, но я незнаю где изменять ip  и у меня нет хостинга(

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте сначала нужен купить хостинг или сервер потом на сайте рег.ру указать настройки домена ДНС сервера который дал Вам уже хостинг провайдер, через 24 часа сайт будет работать, после этого надо уже писать сайт с нулья или использоват ЦМС например вордпресс
за акцент извините не русский :) если будет вопросы пишите

Comment: А если я куплю хостинг он в интернет не уйдет? Просто в каком состояние моя сайт сейчас его нельзя выкладывать)

Comment: Если купите хостинг и установите сайт, будет доступен в интетнету но можно делать так чтобы кроме Вас не кто не смог зайти, через паролью